# Getting Model with nested complex types from Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services, iqueryable, complextype

Hi i'm relatively new to Azure Mobile Apps and Entity Framework so
I've been struggling for a while with the following.

I have the following model on an azure mobile app in .net:

```
public class Location : EntityData
{ 
     public ProximityRange ProximityRange { get; set; }        
     public double Rssi { get; set; }
     public DateTime TimeOfLocation { get; set; }
}
```

where ProximityRange is just a container class for two other properties

```
public class ProximityRange
{
     public double Distance { get; set; }

     public double Accuracy { get; set; }
}
```

The controller has a method to get all Locations by a query.

```
public IQueryable<Location> GetAllLocations()
{
   var query =  Query();
   return query;

}
```

But when I call the controller I only get a JSON with the TimeOfLocation and the Rssi.

In the DB table of the entity Location I have 3 columns

```
ProximityRange_Accuracy, ProximityRange_Distance and Rssi
```

I need to get all 3 properties from the controller GetAllLocations as a JSON Object.

I've tried using $expand=ProximityRange in the query but throws an internal error.

I've also tried declaring ProximityRange as a ComplexType but no luck either.

Would much appreciate someones help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (without some difficulty) use complex types (like DbGeography or your ProximityRange) in Azure Mobile Apps models.  The OData translation doesn't deal with them.

The best idea is to translate it to a string, then implement a JSON encoder/decoder.  The class to look at is a [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm)

Comment: So you mean to avoid using azure mobile services but create a custom api which converts json request and response. Do I understand correct?

Comment: No - you can still transfer the string representation through mobile apps SDKs.  You just need to deal with the conversion to a real geography.  This is mostly because different platforms represent geography differently - it's a DbGeography in the database, but can be other representations in the client-side model.